# Cannot edit embed message with reaction command in discord.py

Tags: python, discord, discord.py

I have been working on a discord bot for a bit now, and now wanting to make it so that the bot calculates the average of the reactions/votes and changes it to the message footer. I have gotten everything else to work, however I can't seem to fiqure out how to edit the message.

Code siplified.

```
#imports

intents = discord.Intents.default()
intents.message_content = True
intents.members = True
intents.dm_messages = True

#bot client
client = discord.Client(intents=intents)

@client.event
async def on_ready():
    print(f'Logged in as {client.user}')

divider=0
sumofnumbers=0
average=0

@client.event
async def on_message(message):
      if message.content.startswith('!viikonlista'):
        embed=discord.Embed(color=0x76b52f)
        embed.add_field(name="Vote now!", value="Votes appear on the footer")
        embed.set_footer(text=average)
        msg=await message.channel.send("Here's the embed!",embed=embed)
        await msg.add_reaction("1️⃣")
        await msg.add_reaction("2️⃣")
        await msg.add_reaction("3️⃣")
        await msg.add_reaction("4️⃣")
        await msg.add_reaction("5️⃣")


@client.event
async def on_reaction_add(reaction, user):
    global divider
    global sumofnumbers
    global average
    if reaction.emoji == "1️⃣" and not user.bot:
      divider+=1
      sumofnumbers+=1
      average=(sumofnumbers)/divider
      embed.set_footer(text=average)
      msg.edit(embed=embed)
      print(average)
#same for the other numbers

#same but minus

client.run("token")
```

Whenever I react, the folloing error is given:

```
NameError: name 'embed' is not defined
```

Comment: Error seems clear enough, embed is not defined. It's defined in a different function, but you can't access function variables after a function has exited. Hint: Use the `global` keyword to mark a variable as global rather than function local

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The error message is pretty much stating what the issue is here. `embed` isn't defined within the scope of the `on_reaction_add` function.

```py
@client.event
async def on_reaction_add(reaction, user):
    global divider
    global sumofnumbers
    global average
    if reaction.emoji == "1️⃣" and not user.bot:
        divider += 1
        summat += 1
        keskiarvo = (sumofnumbers) / divider
        embeds = reaction.message.embeds
        if embeds:
            embed = embeds[0]
        else:
            # no embed
            return

        embed.set_footer(text=average)
        msg.edit(embed=embed)
        print(average)
```

You can get the the message embeds by looking at `embeds` property on the Message object via the `reaction.message` property.

Or, alternatively, create a new instance of the embed here and then do what you want to do.

Docs:

- [reaction](https://discordpy.readthedocs.io/en/stable/api.html#discord.Reaction)
- [message](https://discordpy.readthedocs.io/en/stable/api.html#discord.Message)
- [embed](https://discordpy.readthedocs.io/en/stable/api.html#discord.Embed)